# error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription

Tags: angular

I am facing one problem while working in Angular 8.

service.ts file

```
 public getTopicsByContainerId(containerId) {
        var result;
        if (this.envUrl.accessMock == true) {
            result = topicsData;
            return of(result.filter(items => items.attributes.ContainerOid == containerId));
        }
        else {
            var url = this.getTopicsByContainerIdEndPoint.replace("{id}", containerId);
            return this.repository.getData(url).subscribe();
        }

    }
```

component.ts file

```
var output = this.homeService.getTopicsByContainerId(container_Oid).subscribe(res => {
   this.currentContainerTopics = res[0];
   });
```

Now the problem is that I am facing the following error while calling the web service from the component file.

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(98,72): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription | Observable<any>'.
  Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
```

can anyone tell me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add return type `Observable<YourType>` to your method `getTopicsByContainerId()` and delete `subscribe` method inside of method `getTopicsByContainerId()`:

```
public getTopicsByContainerId(containerId) : Observable<YourType> {
    var result;
    if (this.envUrl.accessMock == true) {
        result = topicsData;
        return of(result.filter(items => items.attributes.ContainerOid == containerId));
    }
    else {
        var url = this.getTopicsByContainerIdEndPoint.replace("{id}", containerId);
        return this.repository.getData(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: I added your changes but now I am getting some different error.

 @Output()
  selectedTopic: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); 

on this line, I am getting 


error TS1110: Type expected.
@Output()
     ~

Comment: No the above suggestion still giving me the same error

Comment: @JayeshVyas could you create a [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? It is hard to predict without code. Feel free to reproduce your error.

Comment: Hii, I got the root cause, actually just before that line I am declaring a variable and after that by mistake I am using ":" instead of ";" (semicolumn)  thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `.subscribe()`

```js
public getTopicsByContainerId(containerId) {
        var result;
        if (this.envUrl.accessMock == true) {
            result = topicsData;
            return of(result.filter(items => items.attributes.ContainerOid == containerId));
        }
        else {
            var url = this.getTopicsByContainerIdEndPoint.replace("{id}", containerId);
            // return this.repository.getData(url).subscribe();   // remove this line
            return this.repository.getData(url);   // this method should return Observable response
        }

    }
```

Comment: I added your changes but now I am getting some different error. @Output() selectedTopic: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); on this line, I am getting error TS1110: Type expected. @Output() ~

Comment: Can you provide an online link of your code (if possible)

Comment: @Jammer sorry, it will be difficult for me to provide cos I need to set up a lot of things for this

Comment: Check if `EventEmitter` was imported from the correct package ie. from `@angular/core`. Also, it seems complex to guess the problem because your shared code doesn't have the sufficient code like `@Output() selectedTopic: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();` is not present in your question.

Comment: in my comment, I mentioned the line and the error that I am getting in the line